# htaccess rewrite to shorten url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I m in process to upgrade 5 website to a newer version, when the new website is completed i move website to a subfolder v2.

folder structure now

\root\website1\
\root\website2\
\root\website3\
\root\website4\
\root\website5\

folder structure after
\root\v2\website1\ 
\root\v2\website2\ 
etc...

i have create a redirect in htaccess which is working, when user try to access the website
www.example.com/website1, it get redirect to www.example.com/v2/website1, AND the most important part is that the browser is showing www.example.com/website1 without "v2"

```
RewriteRule ^website1/?(.*)$ /v2/website1/$1 [L,NC]
```

but i'm struggling with the following. When someone is access directly www.example.com/v2/website1, the browser is showing v2, which i am trying to hide, so i wonder if some have any idea to i can hide the v2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule to your htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+v[0-9]+/
RewriteRule ^v[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Dear Jon Lin, by adding the rule doesnt work, the browser still display the www.example.com/v2/website1

Comment: @desty_aya As you can see, [those rules work perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0N8Vh.png). Are you sure you don't have something else that's redirecting **back** to the `/v2/` URL? Like are you accessing a directory without a trailing slash?

Comment: i have install a xampp for a quick test. when i go to /root/v2/website1/, it redirect to /root/website1, which is good. But the problem is that it require the files fysically exist on /root/website1, which is not what i want

Comment: @desty_aya you want to keep the rule that you already have that internally rewrites **to** the `/v2/` paths.

Comment: my htaccess is now 
RewriteRule ^website1/?(.*)$ /v2/website1/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+v[0-9]+/
RewriteRule ^v[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
but when i open www.example.com/v2/website1, it try to open /website1 which does not exist

Comment: Dear Jon Lin,somehow your suggestion did indeed solved my problem! I clear the cache of my browser and everything is worked! Thx